# How fill ArrayList dynamically?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I fill an `ArrayList` without determining the `cell` numbers . In other words how can I have an `ArrayList` in which both input values and `cell` numbers are unknown.

For example I don't need to below code, I need that fill `ArrayList` dynamic:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
 arrlist.add(15);
 arrlist.add(22);
 arrlist.add(30);
 arrlist.add(40);
```

I need add these in arrayList dynamic (Loop):

```
arrlist.add(15);
arrlist.add(22);
arrlist.add(30);
arrlist.add(40);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "cell numbers"? The element indices? Should the array list allow for null elements?

Comment: you want to know how can you put unknown values into unknown indices of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling that you're confusing *loop* with *dynamic*, they are two different things. If you want to loop, you can do something like:

```
final int[] ARRAY = {15, 22, 30, 40}; 
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<ARRAY.length;i++) {
    arrlist.add(ARRAY[i]);
}
```

Note that you don't have to specify the initial capacity of the array list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ArrayList.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) - it will append an element to the array list and allocate the space for it if needed, no need to pre-allocate the desired space for the `ArrayList` - that's the point of [Dynamic Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrlist.add(15);
arrlist.add(22);
arrlist.add(30);
arrlist.add(40);
System.out.println(arrlist);
```

If you wish to use loops, you can use a [*for-each loop*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html), assuming you have your elements in some other array/[Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] elements = {15, 22, 30, 40};
for (int x : elements) { 
    arrlist.add(x);
}
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun The `ArrayList`'s `toString()` includes the content, it's not a static array.

Comment: How I can add these dynamic , with loop :arrlist.add(15);
arrlist.add(22);
arrlist.add(30);
arrlist.add(40);

Answer (score 0):

You can istantiate an ArrayList with the command

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
```

Then you can add all the elements you want, and if you want to know the length of your ArrayList, you can use the size method: `list.size();`

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Just don't enter a value when you create a new ArrayList.
You can now enter however many values you want.

EDIT: Woops, someone already answered it while i was typing